# Can someone explain the significance of using uint32_t from the library <stdint.h>?

Tags: c++

I recently saw someones code that was using this variable type and library on code chef. I was wondering if someone can explain the benefits of using `uint32_t` as opposed to `int`, `float`, `double`, etc. Also what cases should I use/not use it?

Link to code: http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/131898

Comment: One benefit is portability. Check [uint32_t vs int as a convention for everyday programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077313/uint32-t-vs-int-as-a-convention-for-everyday-programming).

Comment: An aside, not an answer. Since this question is currently marked c++, you really should be using the C++ header, `<cstdint>`, rather the C header `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: I use it in embedded systems when I have to access hardware devices that 32 bits wide.  This will guarantee that the unsigned integral value will always be 32 bits wide; and the compiler won't shrink it down for something that saves space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage is that a `uint32_t` is always guaranteed to be 32 bits long, as opposed to the primitive types whose lengths are platform-dependent. For instance, while `int`s are 32 bits on x86 and x86_64, they are 64 bits on many other 64-bit platforms, and less than that on some older and/or embedded architectures.

One of the cases where it may be beneficial to use a `uint32_t`, then, could be when you read binary data directly to/from disk/network. You can always just copy 4 bytes into a `uint32_t` and be sure that it fits. (You'd still have to watch out for eg. differences in endianness, however.)

You may also want to use a `uint32_t` if you simply want predictable overflow/underflow behavior. Or if you're doing calculations defined in some specific size, like when running some hashing algorithms.

The only thing I have been left wondering is why there aren't corresponding `float32_t` and `float64_t` types. :)

Comment: About float types: [Fixed-size floating point types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Comment: @JosEdu: That answer pretty much just says the obvious, though; that no such typedefs exist in the standard library.

Comment: A byte isn't necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: While the Standard would in theory allow 32! different storage formats for uint32_t, in practice all systems either store the upper 16 bits followed by the lower 16 bits, or the lower 16 bits followed by the upper 16.  I think there should have been optional explicit uint32be_t and uint32le_t types, with defined aliasing for their constituent parts.  Code using such types could be more readable and easier to process efficiently than code which tries to assemble everything out of bytes.