# What was with the historical typedef soup for integers in C programs?

Tags: c

This is a possibly inane question whose answer I should probably know.

Fifteen years ago or so, a lot of C code I'd look at had tons of integer typedefs in platform-specific `#ifdef`s. It seemed every program or library I looked at had their own, mutually incompatible typedef soup. I didn't know a whole lot about programming at the time and it seemed like a bizarre bunch of hoops to jump through just to tell the compiler what kind of integer you wanted to use.

I've put together a story in my mind to explain what those typedefs were about, but I don't actually know whether it's true. My guess is basically that when C was first developed and standardized, it wasn't realized how important it was to be able to platform-independently get an integer type of a certain size, and thus all the original C integer types may be of different sizes on different platforms. Thus everyone trying to write portable C code had to do it themselves.

Is this correct? If so, how *were* programmers expected to use the C integer types? I mean, in a low level language with a lot of bit twiddling, isn't it important to be able to say "this is a 32 bit integer"? And since the language was standardized in 1989, surely there was some thought that people would be trying to write portable code?

Comment: It seems that a need of platform-independent types has been realized only 10 years later with C99: [stdint.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h)

Comment: 10 years?  C started in 1972 and "K&R C" was 1978.

Comment: another blunder was omitting a true boolean from C89

Comment: @JohnHascall I was referring to first C89 standard.

Comment: @M.M That was outside the scope of the committee's charge "... to develop a clear, consistent, and unambiguous Standard for the C programming language which **codifies the common, existing definition** of C ..." [emphasis mine]

Comment: @M.M: Any Boolean type will necessarily have padding bits, and padding bits create ambiguity in a language.  There is no universally-best way to store Boolean values, and so any specification will either require guarantees that are expensive on at least some systems, or fail to provide guarantees that programmers would sometimes have provided and found useful if they used other types to hold true/false choices.  As defined, the bool type does not provide any way for a program to achieve any required behavior more efficiently than would otherwise be possible.

Comment: This is going to be an unpopular opinion but i think people way overuse `[u]intN_t`. You really don't need a specific number of bits in most cases, you just think you do.

Comment: @Mehrdad Sometimes you need a *consistent* number of bits even though the exact number isn't terribly important.

Comment: @Mehrdad: This is mostly a trade-off betwen a reduced testing burden and performance though (and in theory portability to non-power-of-two architectures). Granted the range guarantees implicit in the integer types or the explicit `[u]int_fastN_t` will do unless doing bit-twiddling. The risk of letting them float free lies in accidentally relying on, say, `long` fitting 64-bits due to primarily testing on a platform where it was. If the performance difference happens to be slight on your particular targets then there is a reasonable argument to be made for always forcing the widths.

Comment: @doynax: I've never accidentally relied on `long` being 64 bits. I use `long long` if I need 64 bits, or `size_t`/`ptrdiff_t` if it's an array index...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Then you are more careful than I. A recent port from 32-bit ARM to an 8-bit architecture turned up a number of 16-bit `int` overflows. Mostly in numeric code where I been to lazy to do proper range analysis. Granted the proper solution is not to be lazy, but I'm sure that I trust myself not to be..

Comment: @immibis: Can you give an example to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @Mehrdad A reproducible simulation (such as in a multiplayer game) might need the same results on all executions, including bugs resulting from overflows. If a variable is 32 bits on one player's machine and 16 bits on another player's machine the game will completely break when it exceeds 65535. (Whereas if it is 16 bits on both players' machines then there might be a localized glitch but it won't break everything else)

Comment: @immibis: For a multiplayer game wouldn't you be shipping binaries rather than source code so wouldn't this be a non-issue? If you allow compiling with different compilers that don't even have the same size for *int*, then you have bigger problems: even with the same number of bits you're very unlikely to get the same results reproduced for floating point operations.

Comment: @Mehrdad What if it's an open source game? Or if you want to ship builds for 32-bit Linux and also 64-bit Linux? Or 64-bit Linux and 64-bit Windows?

Comment: @immibis: How is being open- or closed-source at all relevant to what I just pointed out? The problem is exactly the same...

Comment: @Mehrdad Open-source means you ship source code (maybe as well as binaries)...

Comment: @immibis: Wha...? CPython is open-source yet I always download binaries, and the installers don't even come with the source code... are you making things up as you go?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When C began computers were less homogenous and a lot less connected than today.  It was seen as more important for portability that the int types be the natural size(s) for the computer.  Asking for an exactly 32-bit integer type on a 36-bit system is probably going to result in inefficient code.

And then along came pervasive networking where you are working with specific on-the-wire size fields.  Now interoperability looks a whole lot different. And the 'octet' becomes the de facto quanta of data types.

Now you need ints of exact multiples of 8-bits, so now you get typedef soup and then eventually the standard catches up and we have standard names for them and the soup is not as needed.

Comment: I agree, but I feel that today computers are less heterogeneous than in the late 1990s (remember the Unix wars, and the workstations wars: Appollo, HP, IBM, Sun, ....)

Comment: You're right - I used the opposite word of what I meant - corrected. Thx

Comment: Spot on, this. The variable-width types are, frankly, antiquated for the majority of targets (though still useful in the low-power world). Overall, unless you _know_ that you have a substantial bottleneck due to them, fixed-width types rule okay. You know what they are and you know what they do and you know how big they are.... on either side of a network or file serialisation layer. Now all you need is to be cautious of endianness and alignment and you're set.

Comment: “Asking for an exactly 32-bit integer type on a 36-bit system is probably going to result in inefficient code.” if you need exactly 32bit you can’t get around that anyways. If it just has to be at least 32 bit there is int_fast32_t.

Comment: I am of the apparently minority opinion that even today, if you have good reason to be writing C at all, you generally don't actually need, and shouldn't want, a _fixed_-width integral type: but rather, pick whether you want the smallest or the fastest type that's guaranteed to hold the size you need. The compiler always has the opportunity to know best - tell it how many bits you need, and whether to prefer runtime or runspace efficiency, and let it handle it from there.

Comment: @mtraceur In general I agree, but there are times you need a certain size's be behavior for either interoperability or algorythymic correctness - checksums, sequence number wrap around etc - where having the exact expected size greatly simplifies and speeds things along.

Comment: @mtraceur "The compiler always has the opportunity to know best" → If only that were true. In practice the high-level understanding a human has is far more important than the low-level guesses a compiler engineer can make, and even the "`fast`" integer types are chosen largely arbitrarily.

Comment: @mtraceur: For simple non-exported variables, leastN_t types might make sense, but structures should specify exact types.  I see no good reason the Standard shouldn't allow precise control over structure layout, with a proviso that compilers may reject code that demands layouts they can't support.  One of the reasons C is popular is that on many platforms, functions compiled with different C compilers can call each other.  If one platform defines `int_least16_t` as `int32_t` and another defines it as `int16_t`, any shared types or variables of type `int_least16_t` will be incompatible.

Comment: @Veedrac I wasn't aware that there was a problem with various compilers picking those types "arbitrarily", but in a way that make sense. Thanks for mentioning this. On the other hand, if we write code more optimal than the compiler can produce by demanding a fixed-width int, we've by definition written code that is only optimal for some platforms, today. Is it going to be less optimal on other platforms, and can it prevent more advanced future compiler optimizations? History suggests yes to both. In any case, thanks for the reminder that we shouldn't blindly trust compilers to always do good.

Comment: @mtraceur I'm not particularly worried about power-of-2 integers falling out of popularity any time soon :P. Future compiler optimizations don't seem particularly relevant because the only optimization made possible from using the original types is a *global* different choice of bit-width, rather than local changes, and those global choices are locked in anyway for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @supercat I completely agree we need ways to move fixed-width data between processes for compatibility. But we don't care if my ARMv7 CPU operates on a `char` as a 32-bit register while your x86-64 CPU uses an 8 or 16 or 32 or 64 bit register opcode, right, so long as the result is the same? I think memory layout is kinda like that. Sadly the C standard has failed us in this regard: I think we would've been better served by C requiring library interfaces guaranteeing that for a given least/fast type, we can read/write it on the disk/network side in the respective fixed-width representation.

Comment: @Veedrac I was thinking more like, you might one day get a platform where operating on a 32 bit integer becomes less efficient than operating on a 64 bit integer. I can't think of a case off the top of my head, but I have vague memories of certain operations using extra instructions when operating on sizes that were smaller than the machine's register sizes on some architectures. It might just be a historical concern, no longer relevant today in all but the most peculiar of corner-cases.

Comment: @mtraceur: On nearly *every* platform, there will be at least some situations where code using 32-bit integers can run much faster than code using 64-bit integers--sometimes more than twice as fast--since twice as many 32-bit integers can fit in cache as 64-bit.  Further, many platforms have at least some cases where operations on larger types can be more efficient than operations on smaller ones.

Comment: @mtraceur: It seems to me that the effort required to have a compiler efficiently support a range of integer formats would me much less than the effort required to have a compiler efficiently process portable code to handle those same format (recognizing e.g. that a bunch of byte loads and shifts could be replaced with a 32-bit load and a byte-swap instruction).

Comment: @supercat Well, the compiler might not need to if it was a standard library interface - that interface could be written in per-platform optimized code like other parts of a system library are anyway, right? Still, it might be true that such an interface would actually be best served by having fixed-width types in the standard. _Coupling_ external interfaces and internal memory layout worries me, but as I said in my original message, I'm not against fixed-width types universally, just "generally". Consistent IO among only systems that support fixed-width ints can be a fine reason to use them.

Comment: @mtraceur: The ability to do something like `fread(&myStruct, 1, sizeof myStruct, myFile);` and then use element-access syntax on `myStruct`, rather than having to parse out individual items from memory manually, was one of the advantages that 1980s-1990s C had over some other competing languages, at least in cases where it was unlikely that code would need to be migrated to machines with other memory layouts.  I would regard such code as superior to code that manually fetches items from various structure offsets in all regards *other* that portability, and find it ironic...

Comment: ...that "modern" C requires writing things in clunkier and harder to maintain fashion than older C.  Explicit control of structure layout would make it possible for programs to reap the benefits of 1990s C but without the portability compromises it used to require.

Comment: Right you are. As evidenced by the fact that most people say "byte" to mean "octet" and that very few living programs have ever coded for a non-byte architecture.

Answer (score 18):

C's earlier success was due to it *flexibility* to adapt to nearly all existing variant architectures [@John Hascall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407298/what-was-with-the-historical-typedef-soup-for-integers-in-c-programs#comment73886365_43407298) with:
1) native *integer* sizes of 8, 16, 18, 24, 32, 36, etc. bits,
2) variant signed integer models: 2's complement, 1's complement, signed integer and
3) various endian, big, little and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian).

As coding developed, algorithms and interchange of data pushed for greater uniformity and so the need for types that met 1 & 2 above across platforms.  Coders rolled their own like `typedef int int32` inside a `#if ...`.  The many variations of that created the soup as noted by OP.

---

C99 introduced `(u)int_leastN_t, (u)int_fastN_t, (u)intmax_t` to make portable yet *somewhat* of minimum bit-width-ness types.  These types are required for N = 8,16,32,64.

Also introduced are semi-*optional* types (see below **) like `(u)intN_t` which has the additional attributes of they must be 2's complement and no padding.  It is these popular types that are so widely desired and used to thin out the *integer soup*.

---

> how were programmers expected to use the C integer types?

By writing flexible code that did not strongly rely on bit width.  Is is fairly easy to code `strtol()` using only `LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX` without regard to bit-width/endian/integer encoding.

Yet many coding tasks oblige precise width types and 2's complement for easy high performance coding. It is better in that case to forego portability to 36-bit machines  and 32-bit sign-magnitudes ones and stick with 2<sup>N</sup> wide (2's complement for signed) integers.   Various CRC & crypto algorithms and file formats come to mind.  Thus the need for fixed-width types and a specified (C99) way to do it.

---

Today there are still [gotchas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming)) that still need to be managed.  Example: The usual promotions `int/unsigned` lose some control as those types may be 16, 32 or 64.

---

**

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall deﬁne the corresponding typedef names. C11 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types 3

Comment: I'd give you two up votes if I could for your correct explanation/quoting of the not-really-optionality of the `intN_t` etc types.

Comment: @DanielJour [uint32_t vs int as a convention for everyday programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20077313/2410359)  goes into related issues.

Answer (score 11):

I remember that period and I'm guilty of doing the same!

One issue was the size of `int`, it could be the same as `short`, or `long` or in between. For example, if you were working with binary file formats, it was imperative that everything align. Byte ordering complicated things as well. Many developer went the lazy route and just did `fwrite` of whatever, instead of picking numbers apart byte-by-byte. When the machines upgraded to longer word lengths, all hell broke loose. So `typedef` was an easy hack to fix that.

If performance was an issue, as it often was back then, `int` was guaranteed to be the machine's fastest natural size, but if you needed 32 bits, and `int` was shorter than that, you were in danger of rollover.

In the C language, `sizeof()` is not supposed to be resolved at the preprocessor stage, which made things complicated because you couldn't do `#if sizeof(int) == 4` for example.

Personally, some of the rationale was also just working from an assembler language mindset and not being willing to abstract out the notion of what `short`, `int` and `long` are for. Back then, assembler was used in C quite frequently.

Nowadays, there are plenty of non-binary file formats, JSON, XML, etc. where it doesn't matter what the binary representation is. As well, many popular platforms have settled on a 32-bit `int` or longer, which is usually enough for most purposes, so there's less of an issue with rollover.

Comment: I thought one could assert at compile time using the diagnostic for an attempt to declare a negatively sized array: `extern const char int_is_4_bytes[sizeof(int) == 4 ? 1 : -1];` Or was this not widely known?

Comment: @DamianYerrick that only lets you error out when the typedefs are incorrect and then requires manual correction. It won't let you select a correct typedef a priori `#if sizeof(long) == 8 \ #define int64 long \ #elif sizeof(long long) == 8 \ #define int64 long long \ #endif`

Comment: "most platforms have settled on a 32-bit int or larger" --> Hmmm, at least 100s of millions of embedded process each year (2016) use 16-bit `int`.  C is very popular there.

Comment: "you couldn't do `#if sizeof(int) == 4` for example" -> while this has never been standard, several compilers did (and still do) actually support this. Presumably exactly to address the difficulty in handling it any other way before `stdint.h` came along.

Comment: From what I remember of the time, portability could be improved by avoiding the use of "int" for things other than simple automatic, or maybe static, variables.  For anything else, use either `short` or `long`.  Compilers for platforms where `int` was 16 bits would recognize that `int*` and `short*` could alias, and those where `int` was 32 bits would recognize that `int*` and `long*` could alias.  Adding `int32_t` but not specifying that it would be alias-compatible with other integer types using the same size and representation was not an improvement, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

C is a product of the early 1970s, when the computing ecosystem was very different.  Instead of millions of computers all talking to each other over an extended network, you had maybe a hundred thousand systems worldwide, each running a few monolithic apps, with almost no communication between systems.  You *couldn't* assume that any two architectures had the same word sizes, or represented signed integers in the same way.  The market was still small enough that there wasn't any percieved need to standardize, computers didn't talk to each other (much), and nobody though much about portability.

> If so, how were programmers expected to use the C integer types?

If you wanted to write maximally portable code, then you didn't assume anything beyond what the Standard guaranteed.  In the case of `int`, that meant you didn't assume that it could represent anything outside of the range `[-32767,32767]`, nor did you assume that it would be represented in 2's complement, nor did you assume that it was a specific width (it could be wider than 16 bits, yet still only represent a 16 bit range if it contained any padding bits).

If you didn't care about portability, or you were doing things that were inherently non-portable (which bit twiddling usually is), then you used whatever type(s) met your requirements.

I did mostly high-level applications programming, so I was less worried about representation than I was about range.  Even so, I occasionally needed to dip down into binary representations, and it always bit me in the ass.  I remember writing some code in the early '90s that had to run on classic MacOS, Windows 3.1, and Solaris.  I created a bunch of enumeration constants for 32-bit masks, which worked fine on the Mac and Unix boxes, but failed to compile on the Windows box because on Windows an `int` was only 16 bits wide.

Comment: Microcomputer C compilers almost without exception used 8/16/32 bits for char/short/long and used two's-complement signed representations.  The only things that varied *in the general-purpose-microcomputer world* were whether "int" was 16 or 32 bits, and whether they were big-endian or little-endian.  Things were different with machines other than general-purpose microcomputers, but a lot of programs would not have been useful on such machines anyway.

Answer (score 2):

C was designed as a language that could be ported to as wide a range of machines as possible, rather than as a language that would allow most kinds of programs to be run without modification on such a range of machines.  For most practical purposes, C's types were:

- An 8-bit type if one is available, or else the smallest type that's at least 8 bits.
- A 16-bit type, if one is available, or else the smallest type that's at least 16 bits.
- A 32-bit type, if one is available, or else some type that's at least 32 bits.
- A type which will be 32 bits if systems can handle such things as efficiently as 16-bit types, or 16 bits otherwise.

If code needed 8, 16, or 32-bit types and would be unlikely to be usable on machines which did not support them, there wasn't any particular problem with such code regarding `char`, `short`, and `long` as 8, 16, and 32 bits, respectively.  The only systems that didn't map those names to those types would be those which couldn't support those types and wouldn't be able to usefully handle code that required them.  Such systems would be limited to writing code which had been written to be compatible with the types that they use.

I think C could perhaps best be viewed as a recipe for converting system specifications into language dialects.  A system which uses 36-bit memory won't really be able to efficiently process the same language dialect as a system that use octet-based memory, but a programmer who learns one dialect would be able to learn another merely by learning what integer representations the latter one uses.  It's much more useful to tell a programmer who needs to write code for a 36-bit system, "This machine is just like the other machines except `char` is 9 bits, `short` is 18 bits, and `long` is 36 bits", than to say "You have to use assembly language because other languages would all require integer types this system can't process efficiently".

Comment: "C was not designed as a language that could be ported to as wide a range of machines as possible". I'm not sure what you mean by this. Wasn't C born into the UNIX environment for the sole purpose of eliminating inconsistent interfaces for files and so on?

Comment: @Seb: Mea culpa.  I started by saying it wasn't designed to facilitate portable programs, but rather to be a language that was portable, but then I reversed the order and accidentally left an extra "not".  Better now?

Comment: Fantastic! It's a shame there aren't any types which *guarantee* the portable ranges of `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` (and their `unsigned` equivalents), without going above and beyond those ranges, *even at the expense of meaningless padding*... or better yet, the ability for the programmer to specify the ranges he/she cares about; this would virtually eliminate misunderstandings regarding portability of ranges of types such as `int` and `long` that exist nowadays, and provide useful internal documentation within the code to facilitate maintenance. Again, nice answer!

Comment: @Seb: I would really like to see C include a way of specifying exactly what one needs: "32 bits non-promoting unsigned, stored as four possibly-padded 8-bit chunks, big-endian, accessible at 32-bit boundaries, and alias-compatible with all similar types."  A compiler whose "uint32_t" has those characteristics could simply use "uint32_t", but code could using such types could also work on systems where uint32_t doesn't have those characteristics if they support types that do.

Answer (score 1):

Not all machines have the same native word size.  While you might be tempted to think a smaller variable size will be more efficient, it just ain't so.   In fact, using a variable that is the same size as the native word size of the CPU is much, much faster for arithmetic, logical and bit manipulation operations.

But what, exactly, is the "native word size"?  Almost always, this means the register size of the CPU, which is the same as the Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) can work with.

In embedded environments, there are still such things as 8 and 16 bit CPUs (are there still 4-bit PIC controllers?).  There are mountains of 32-bit processors out there still.  So the concept of "native word size" is alive and well for C developers.

With 64-bit processors, there is often good support for 32-bit operands.  In practice, using 32-bit integers and floating point values can often be faster than the full word size.

Also, there are trade-offs between native word alignment and overall memory consumption when laying out C structures.

But the two common usage patterns remain: size agnostic code for improved speed (int, short, long), or fixed size (int32_t, int16_t, int64_t) for correctness or interoperability where needed.

Comment: `int`/`short`/`long` are *not* size-agnostic. They have specified sizes on any given platform. Performance is application- and algorithm-dependant, and blindly using arbitrarily sized types thinking "the compiler will sort it out for me" isn't a good way to write fast code. In theory clever use of the `u?int_fast\d*_t` types can help here, but in practice you're still better-off just benchmarking for the specific platforms you want.

Comment: @Veedrac: Performance could be enhanced if there were types that were allowed to hold values outside their "normal" range at the compiler's convenience without a requirement that they behave consistently.  On some systems, using 16-bit types for variables kept in registers may require that a compiler add otherwise-unneeded code to truncate values to 16 bits, but using 16-bit types for variables kept in arrays would improve cache performance.  A type that would allow 16-bit variables in memory but not promise truncation might offer optimal performance, but C defines no such thing.

Comment: @supercat The compiler is always allowed to do that if you tell it that it's UB! That's what the "as-if" rule is about. Unfortunately C does poorly thought-out things like making whether wraparound is defined a property of the signedness type (WTF?) rather than the operation, which means it's often challenging to tell the compiler that the transformations are valid. This isn't any more or less a problem with `short`/`int`/`long` than it is with the fixed-width types, though; it's just a problem with C.

Comment: @Veedrac: A conforming 32-bit implementation, given `int16_t foo;` and asked to executing `foo++;` when `foo` is 32767, will be required by the Standard as either set `foo` to "an implementation-defined value" (typically -32768) or raise an implementation-defined signal.  While a programmer could add extra code to induce UB if `foo` was 32767 (and hope the compiler doesn't generate any machine code for that) I find backward the notion that programmers should be expected to write useless code in the hope that optimizers will eliminate it.

Comment: @Veedrac: On a system with 32-bit `int`, incrementing an `int32_t` or a 32-bit `int_least16_t beyond its range would invoke UB.  Incrementing an `int16_t` or a 16-bit `int_least16_t` beyond its range, however, would be required to either yield a value within the range of `int16_t` or else raise an implementation-defined signal.  On some systems, both options would have costs which wouldn't apply if an implementation could treat `int_least16_t` as sometimes being able to hold numbers larger than 32767.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141795/discussion-between-veedrac-and-supercat).

Comment: @Veedrac, On any given chip/cpu/architecture, you are correct.  But many developers write code that must compile and run on many different chips.  In my experience, this is the most common requirement.  I have many times had to write code that builds and runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit (or 16-bit and 32-bit, back in the day).   In the same routine, int, short and long may have different physical sizes when built on these different architectures.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel "int, short and long may have different physical sizes when built on these different architectures" → Exactly, code that uses `int`/`short`/`long` is less portable.

Comment: @Veedrac, that isn't my personal experience.  But it isn't one-size-fits-all.   So long as your application data works within the minimum size, it is more portable and more performant in any given port.   As a practical matter, most applications have app-specific typedefs that resolve to either a fixed size type (`uint32_t`, etc.) or "native" type (`int`, `short`, `long`) according to the needs of the app.

Comment: @CharlieReitzel `long` is almost never faster than `int32_t`, and frequently slower, sometimes a lot slower. The idea that using the less portable types is somehow faster is a myth.